# Pagefactory initialization

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I implemented a framework with POM and Page Factory approach. I have a baseTest class with lots of init e.g: (every other test class extends it)

```
Registration regPage = PageFactory.initelements(driver,Registration.class);
Login loginPage = PageFactory.initelements(driver,login.class);
Details detailsPage = PageFactory.initelements(driver,details.class);
.. (more than 10)
```

It is working fine but I would like to find more elegant/structured way to handle it.

I tried the build it into the constructor:

```
public Registeration(WebDriver driver) {
super(driver);
PageFactory.initelements(driver,Registration.class(or can be this));
}
```

It this case, I got a huge heapmemory error however it would be very nice because I could use an assert to validate every pageObject in the constructor using title or whatever element on the page, right?

How can I structure my inits and how can I handle it with PageFactory using constructor?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a factory if it needs as an argument the type of the instance it's returning, it's a kludge around `new` and a constructor. Just initialize in the constructor. The pseudo-factory approach will severely damage maintainability and extensibility.

Comment: You spelled a type `Registration` but its constructor `Registeration`. Be careful.

Comment: Have you read the docs or any guides on `PageFactory`? They explain how to use it properly. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory

Comment: Thanks, JeffC, that was an interesting read.  I already used all the functionality it showed in all my PO's, but it was nice to be able to confirm that I hadn't missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Its because initElements stuck in infinite loop. PageFactory's InitElement function looks first for page's constructor with webdriver argument. Its like Page Creation call by your runner --> initElements (2nd line)--> Page Constructor called by initElements and this keeps circling around. So, you cannot initiate the page class within constructor of page using pagefactory. You may structure something like this

```
    public class MyTest{
    @Test
    public void test(){
        TestFactory.invokeBrowser();
        MyPage page = TestFactory.getPage(MyPage.class);
    }
    }

//TestFactory class
    public class TestFactory{
    private static WebDriver driver;

    public static void invokeBrowser(){
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    //invokes the browser
    this.driver = driver;
    }

    public static <T> T getPage(Class<T> page){
    return PageFactory.initElements(driver,page);
    }
    }
```